# How to add strings together with in a .each loop in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am having so trouble joining up strings within jquery. I have tried a number of ways but keep over writing the first string variable leaving just the last entry.

My strings are coming in through a loop where the loop gets the val of some input boxes. It needs to be done like this as the script will eventually add more input boxes when user needs them and so they will not have individual id's.

The code is below, what i am trying to get on the output div is the following

"Apple,Fruit,10,Carrot,Veg,5,test,test2,8"

but at the moment i am only getting "88,"

```js
var value = '';
$('#submit').click(function(){
  $('li').each(function(){
    $('input').each(function(){
      value = $(this).val();
      value += value + ',';
    })
  })
  $('#out').html(value);
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
      integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
</head>
  <body>
    <ul id="ingrediants">
      <li>
        <input type="text" value="Apple" data-id="itemName">
        <input type="text" value="Fruit" data-id="description">
        <input type="text" value="10" data-id="qty">
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="text" value="Carrot" data-id="itemName">
        <input type="text" value="Veg" data-id="description">
        <input type="text" value="5" data-id="qty">
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="text" value="test" data-id="itemName">
        <input type="text" value="test2" data-id="description">
        <input type="text" value="8" data-id="qty">
      </li>
    </ul>
    <button id="submit">Submit</button>
    <div id="out"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0wL12vbs/

Comment: @BrettGregson Straight up answers should be posted as answers, not comments

Comment: @Taplar by the time my fiddle was created there were 4 answers, no point in repeating another similar answer, and no point in wasting the fiddle

Comment: You're missing the point.  Just as we discourage people from making questions that consist only of links to external snippet sites, the same goes for answers, and comment that **should** be answers. @BrettGregson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reassigning the `value` variable each time in your `for-loop`. Change it to the following:

```
var value = '';
$('#submit').click(function(){
  $('li').each(function(){
    $('input').each(function(){
      value += $(this).val() + ',';
    })
  })
  $('#out').html(value);
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Just select all the inputs, map their values, and then join them by commas.  You don't need to explicitly write the each statements.

```
value = $('li input').map((index, it) => it.value).get().join(',');
```

Working sample:

```js
$('#submit').click(function() {
  // arrow function supported browsers
  var value = $('li input').map((index, it) => it.value).get().join(',');
  // non-arrow function supported browsers (older IE for example)
  var value = $('li input').map(function(index, it) { return it.value; }).get().join(',');
  $('#out').text(value);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="ingrediants">
  <li>
    <input type="text" value="Apple" data-id="itemName">
    <input type="text" value="Fruit" data-id="description">
    <input type="text" value="10" data-id="qty">
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="text" value="Carrot" data-id="itemName">
    <input type="text" value="Veg" data-id="description">
    <input type="text" value="5" data-id="qty">
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="text" value="test" data-id="itemName">
    <input type="text" value="test2" data-id="description">
    <input type="text" value="8" data-id="qty">
  </li>
</ul>
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
<div id="out"></div>
```

Comment: This did not work, do you have any links where I can learn this or is it just jquery map that i need to search

Comment: It should be `map((i, it) => it.value)`. This approach is by far the best way to do what you need, though

Comment: Added a working sample of `.map` as it's much more succinct that using a for loop and powerful tool to learn: https://api.jquery.com/map/

Comment: Ahhhh, I forgot the index that jQuery injects.  :(

Comment: @freedomn-m updated the snippet you added to use the correct arrow function version

Comment: No worries - I still don't use `=>` because *still* have to support IE11

Comment: @freedomn-m added both versions.  Yeah, I'm actually fixing to start a project that has to support older IE.  But we're probably going to use babel (hopefully) so we don't have to worrry about a lot of that stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You are resetting the value of your `value` variable in the loop.

```js
var value = '';
$('#submit').click(function(){
  $('li').each(function(){
    $('input').each(function(){
      value = $(this).val(); //THIS LINE!
      value += $(this).val() + ","; //USE THIS INSTEAD
      value += value + ',';
    })
  })
  $('#out').html(value);
})
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to remove the 'li' each:

Like so:

EDIT:

```
var value = '';
$('#submit').click(function(){
    $('input').each(function(){
      value += $(this).val() + ',';
    })
  $('#out').html(value);
})
```

Comment: You're still reassigning the `value` variable in your `each-loop`. Plus you will take all `inputs` outside the `li` list as well, which isn't wanted in this case.

Comment: Sure, I was at lunch, on the cellphone and stuff... and missed that :P